# Как получить все заголовки/названия разделов ресурсов PE файла (.exe)?

Tags: c#, exe, ресурсы, pe

Как получить название всех заголовков разделов .exe файла? Например как через ресурс хакер на фото. Можно в C# эти заголовки найти, отпарсить?

[image: заголовки]

Comment: Видимо, придется вооружится документацией по составу PE файла, прочитать в массив байт файл и начать с нужным смещением читать/искать эти заголовки и их значения.

Comment: @Bulson Я изучаю информацию о структурах PE файлов. Эти заголовки это "Название секции"? То есть PE файл разбит на секции и если я хочу узнать название этих заголовков, то мне нужно вручную найти "Название секции"?

Comment: Может быть... у меня сейчас не открыта такая документация, потому определено точно сказать не имею возможности.

Comment: http://cs.usu.edu.ru/docs/pe/sections.html тут смотрю

Comment: Тут еще может понадобится hex редактор. В нем можно открыть тот же файл `chrome.exe` и сравнить с тем, что выводит эта ResourceHacker. Но, надо заметить, что вы не тот инструмент для такой работы выбрали, я имею в виду `C#` и копание в потрохах файлов. `C#` - язык для быстрого и комфортного написания прикладных программ, а низкоуровневая работа с файлами - это системное программирование, такую работу делают на `C` или `C++`.

Comment: К сожалению нужно именно на c#. Ладно, главное понять принцип, буду разбираться

Comment: Изучайте формат секции ресурсов и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @Bulson разве чтение файла это низкоуровневое программирование? Тут вообще яп не важен

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=c%23+pe+file+reader

Comment: @PrimusSingularis спасибо! не знал как сформулировать запрос

Comment: https://gist.github.com/caioproiete/b51f29f74f5f5b2c59c39e47a8afc3a3 - кажется то что нужно

Comment: @PrimusSingularis Не системное программирование, но в Си можно запросто привести указатель на массив к указателю на структуру и работать с ней. При должной аккуратности получается более удобно при разборе бинарных данных, чем потоки данных и методы из Marshal в .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В среде Windows - c помощью функции [EnumResourceTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648039(v=vs.85).aspx). Технически, это называется не заголовками, а типами ресурсов: стандарт PE определяет структуру секции ресурсов как дерево произвольной вложенности, но на практике используется три уровня - *Type*, *Name* и *Language*. То, что на картинке - это *Type*.

При использовании функции следует учесть следующее:

- Предварительно нужно загрузить изучаемый модуль в память процесса. Предпочтительно для этого использовать функцию `LoadLibraryEx` с флагом `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`. При такой загрузке не выполняется никакой код из этого модуля, что позволяет улучшить производительность, обойти ограничение на загрузку 64-битных модулей в 32-битные процессы, а также уменьшает шансы наткнуться на очередную уязвимость и выполнить чей-то вредоносный код в своем процессе.
- Тип ресурса может определяться как строкой (обычно, для нестандартных ресурсов) так и идентификатором (обычно, для стандартных типов ресурсов). Чтобы их различать и получать осмысленные значения для каждого случая, нужно взять из заголовочных файлов Windows SDK специальные макросы: `IS_INTRESOURCE`, `GET_RESOURCE_ID`, `GET_RESOURCE_NAME`. Однако, для нестандартных ресурсов, определяемых идентификатором, строковое представление имени получить не получится - его знает только сама изучаемая программа.

Вспомогательный класс для получения списка типов ресурсов (топорная реализация только для примера, не используйте статические переменные для промежуточных результатов в реальных проектах!):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

public static class Resources
{
    /* Источник: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.EnumResourceNames */

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hReservedNull, LoadLibraryFlags dwFlags);

    public delegate bool EnumResTypeProc(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr lpszType, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool EnumResourceTypes(IntPtr hModule, EnumResTypeProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    public static bool IS_INTRESOURCE(IntPtr value)
    {
        if (((uint)value) > ushort.MaxValue)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static uint GET_RESOURCE_ID(IntPtr value)//преобразование указателя в ID ресурса
    {
        if (IS_INTRESOURCE(value) == true)
            return (uint)value;
        throw new System.NotSupportedException("value is not an ID!");
    }
    public static string GET_RESOURCE_NAME(IntPtr value)//преобразование указателя в имя ресурса
    {
        if (IS_INTRESOURCE(value) == true)
            return value.ToString();
        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)value);
    }

    /** ************************************************************ */

    public static List<string> ResourceTypes = new List<string>();//список для промежуточного хранения строк

    public static bool EnumProc(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr lpszType, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (ResourceTypes == null) ResourceTypes = new List<string>();

        string str;
        if (IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszType))//ресурс определяется ID
        {
            str = ((ResType)GET_RESOURCE_ID(lpszType)).ToString();//преобразование ID в строку
        }
        else
        {
            str = GET_RESOURCE_NAME(lpszType);//ресурс определяется именем
        }
        ResourceTypes.Add(str);//добавление строки в список            

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение списка типов ресурсов для модуля
    /// </summary>        
    public static List<string> GetResourceTypes(string file)
    {
        //загрузим модуль...
        IntPtr h = LoadLibraryEx(file, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
        if (h == IntPtr.Zero) throw new ApplicationException("LoadLibraryEx failed!");

        ResourceTypes = new List<string>();//очистка списка

        EnumResourceTypes(h, EnumProc, IntPtr.Zero);//запуск процесса перечисления ресурсов

        return ResourceTypes;
    }
    /** ************************************************************ */
}

[System.Flags]
public enum LoadLibraryFlags : uint
{
    ZERO = 0,
    DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001,
    LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x00000010,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = 0x00000020,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR = 0x00000200,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS = 0x00001000,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR = 0x00000100,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 = 0x00000800,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS = 0x00000400,
    LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008
}

/// <summary>
/// Идентификаторы для типов стандартных ресурсов
/// </summary>
public enum ResType : uint
{
    CURSOR = 1,
    BITMAP = 2,
    ICON = 3,
    MENU = 4,
    DIALOG = 5,
    STRING = 6,
    FONTDIR = 7,
    FONT = 8,
    ACCELERATOR = 9,
    RCDATA = 10,
    MESSAGETABLE = 11,
    GROUP_CURSOR = 12,
    GROUP_ICON = 14,
    VERSION = 16,
    DLGINCLUDE = 17,
    PLUGPLAY = 19,
    VXD = 20,
    ANICURSOR = 21,
    ANIICON = 22,
    HTML = 23,
    MANIFEST = 24
}
```

Пример использования:

```
List<string> lst = Resources.GetResourceTypes("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(300);
foreach (var x in lst) sb.AppendLine(x);

if (lst.Count == 0) MessageBox.Show("No resources");
else MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(),"Resource types");
```

Comment: Это фантастика.  Спасибо огромное!